# Parsing Requests Module Response JSON

Tags: pandas, python-requests, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use the [OpenMeteo API][1] to download CSVs via script. Using their API Builder, and their click-able site, I am able to do it for a single site just fine.

In trying to write a function to accomplish this in a loop via the `requests` library, I am stumped. I CANNOT get the json data OUT of the type `requests.model.Response` and into a JSON or even better CSV/ Pandas format.

Cannot parse the requests module response to anything. It appears to succeed ("200" response), and have data, but I cannot get it out of the response format!

```
latitude= 60.358
longitude= -148.939

request_txt=r"https://archive-api.open-meteo.com/v1/archive?latitude="+ str(latitude)+"&longitude="+ str(longitude)+ "&start_date=1959-01-01&end_date=2023-02-10&models=era5_land&daily=temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,temperature_2m_mean,shortwave_radiation_sum,precipitation_sum,rain_sum,snowfall_sum,et0_fao_evapotranspiration&timezone=America%2FAnchorage&windspeed_unit=ms"


r=requests.get(request_txt).json()


  [1]: https://open-meteo.com/en/docs/historical-weather-api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url needs format=csv added as a parameter. StringIO is used to download as an object into memory.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests


latitude = 60.358
longitude = -148.939

url = ("https://archive-api.open-meteo.com/v1/archive?"
       f"latitude={latitude}&"
       f"longitude={longitude}&"
       "start_date=1959-01-01&"
       "end_date=2023-02-10&"
       "models=era5_land&"
       "daily=temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,temperature_2m_mean,"
       "shortwave_radiation_sum,precipitation_sum,rain_sum,snowfall_sum,"
       "et0_fao_evapotranspiration&"
       "timezone=America%2FAnchorage&"
       "windspeed_unit=ms&"
       "format=csv")

with requests.Session() as request:
    response = request.get(url, timeout=30)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(response.raise_for_status())


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), sep=",", skiprows=2)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I had the request set up incorrectly; was too focused on trying to figure out the response. Got to watch out for that tunnel vision :)